# How to add column in dataframe with increasing value consisting aplha-numeric and another column with random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df :

how to insert a column with increasing values to the whole table

df :

```
   0 
1  a 
2  b
3  c
```

expected ouput :

```
        0         1
    1   a       pa001
    2   b       pa002
    3   c       pa003
```

......
for another part have a df and how to insert random intergers in range

like  `randint(3.5,4.5)`  to whole table

df :

```
   0 
1  a 
2  b
3  c
```

output :

```
   0   |   1
1  a   |  3.5
2  b   |  3.6
3  c   |  3.7
```

Comment: `random intergers in range` you mean random? And integers? From your example they don't seem neither of these

Comment: i meant both decimals and floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use f-strings in list comprehension:

```
df['a'] = [f'pa{x:03}' for x in range(1, len(df)+1)]
```

Or convert index to strings and use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['a'] = 'pa' +  df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(3)
```

If possible index values are different create `Series` by `np.arange`:

```
df['a'] = 'pa' +  pd.Series(1, np.arange(len(df) + 1)).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
```

And then use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
#if need counter
df['b'] = np.arange(3.5, len(df) * 0.1 + 3.5, 0.1)
#if need random between
df['c'] = np.random.uniform(3.5, 4.5, len(df))
print (df)
   0      a    b         c
1  a  pa001  3.5  4.137877
2  b  pa002  3.6  4.380499
3  c  pa003  3.7  3.799172
```

Comment: for second one i am getting list indices must be intergers or slices not str

Comment: `df['b'] = np.arange(3.5, len(df) * 0.1 + 3.5, 0.1)
#if need random between
df['c'] = np.random.uniform(3.5, 4.5, len(df))
print (df)`

Comment: getting list indices must be intergers or slices , not str

Comment: @elmantospetus - hmm, error is not from `df['a'] = 'pa' +  df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(3)` ? If remove it, how working it?